# AVFoundation.AVAudioPlayer stops randomly

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to play multiple sounds at the same time. However sometimes the sounds just stops playing or never starts at all.

I have an eventhandler that recieves an event when a sound effect should be played:

```
void HandlePlaySound (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.InvokeOnMainThread (()=>{
            ...
             [set url to path]  
            ...
            MonoTouch.AVFoundation.AVAudioPlayer player = MonoTouch.AVFoundation.AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(url);
            player.Play();
        });
    }
```

This works fine most of the time but when two sounds gets triggered at the same time it's seems like one of them will be killed or both. I must be doing something really wrong here.

Is there a more correct way of playing sounds in an iPhone app. Each sound is supposed to play till end and there could be multiple sounds playing at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were to guess, I'd say that sometimes, the GC comes in and disposes the player that has gone out of scope, causing your random stop behaviour. I found a stable solution being first establishing how many simultaneous audio streams you'd *like* to able to play, and then enforcing those rules:

```
    // I'd like a maximum of 5 simultaneous audio streams
    Queue<AVAudioPlayer> players = new Queue<AVAudioPlayer>(5);

    void PlayAudio (string fileName)
    {
        NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromFilename(fileName);
        AVAudioPlayer player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(url);

        if (players.Count == 5) {
            players.Dequeue().Dispose();
        }
        players.Enqueue(player);
        player.Play();
    }

    // In my example, I'll select files from my Sounds folder (containing a couple of .wav, a couple of .mp3 and an .aif)
    string[] files;
    int fileIndex = 0;

    string GetNextFileName ()
    {
        if (files == null)
            files = Directory.GetFiles("Sounds");

        if (fileIndex == files.Length)
            fileIndex = 0;
        return files[fileIndex++];
    }

    partial void OnPlayButtonTapped (NSObject sender)
    {
        string fileName = GetNextFileName();
        PlayAudio(fileName);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Sami! That actually led me to a solution. It was probably the GC.

Comment: @Sami Lamti: something is wrong here. you are not doing anything with the wave file you opened for reading.

Comment: Good Eye @henon; thanks! I've updated the code example :)